# Reliability of CCS GCM when sending downstream message

Tags: java, android, xmpp, google-cloud-messaging

I have a question on the reliability of CCS GCM theory of Google. I have followed the below link and set up a server and made a chat client in Android.

I can send upstream message, it gets delivered well in time. When I wanted to do a broadcast directly from the server to devices which are in the list I followed the below code.

I made a for loop:

```
for(int i= 0; i< 100; i++){
                Date date = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
                DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss:SSS");
                String dateFormatted = formatter.format(date);
                payload.put("message",  dateFormatted + " "+Integer.valueOf(i).toString());
                messageId = getRandomMessageId();
                sInstance.send(createJsonMessage("APA91bEfm0B4q02oZWMm-Kda47aKktcMpdSedxWfgti46T10-HVeIU9wjsuXZHrwly8xzweO20CrvCbAZdrTo9tTq238uz8j8a8yw-a_9_mvKuOAaxmSF2M0-La3fQuUCIZmmmFkDMrGe-oLcGuzzFBt6KOu3JjPg_mQ_ohqDMyT_rQx9CTbBxE", messageId, payload,collapseKey, timeToLive, delayWhileIdle));                   
                   try {
                        Thread.sleep(10000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(SmackCcsClient.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
            }
```

However I get fistful of messages at Android end. I have sent 100 odd messages, some times I received 20, sometime 10, sometimes 50 messages.

Is it not possible to create chat application(broadcast chat) with CCS?

N:B: I am getting acknowledgements from Google as soon as I fire the message. Why Google is not delivering? I am trying with 1 device now, in future, I am planning to have 100000 device message sending. Is it possible or not?

Comment: For thousands of devices, the delivery rate of GCM (without CSS) seems to be around 80%. At least, that's what I've heard. What you're getting seems kind of low.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk, I am using the new payload by referring this URL http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/ccs.html, its different that normal GCM payload...however the receiving rate is pretty low. Do you have any guess?

Comment: @StephanBranczyk its CCS

Comment: No, if I had a guess, I would have said something.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk I guess thats the end of CCS at my end. I am not going to use this any of my app from now on....I am fed up with this technology